# View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, mysql-connector

I'm new to AndroidStudio, and I'm working on MySQL connection with JDBC lib.

I have no error with compiling but when I run my app, I'm getting this error:

> appname has stopped.

Thank you.

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                Process: com.example.root14.yourapp, PID: 6784
>                                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                    at com.example.root14.yourapp.tab1.onCreateView(tab1.java:25)
>                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2080)
>                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108)
>                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1290)
>                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801)
>                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1638)
>                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:679)
>                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
>                                                                                    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1240)
>                                                                                    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1088)
>                                                                                    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1614)
>                                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19731)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
>                                                                                    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:700)
>                                                                                    at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
>                                                                                    at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1364)
>                                                                                    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:765)
>                                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19731)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
>                                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
>                                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19731)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
>                                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19731)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
>                                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19731)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
>                                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19731)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6120)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:687)
>                                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19731)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2271)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1358)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1607)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1246)
>                                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6301)
>                                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
>                                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
>                                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
>                                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   04-08 22:01:09.999 6784-6784/com.example.root14.yourapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

Comment: Generally speaking, Android should not use direct JDBC connection for security and performance reasons.

Comment: post some code, those two answers should be a comment! as is , the error range is too large

Comment: JDBC is for vanilla java, it is not optimized for android operating system, there is sqlite, but i recommend a faster approach such realm  which is nosql. transactions are based on object relational mappings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2):

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Did you tried to debug and check the app for above Null pointer exception?

It seems code is trying to access element which is not present in the content_main.xml or activity_main.xml. Hope this helps.